# How to show dirty values when debugging entity

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I need use `_get` so I just did it at `User entity` just for test:

```
protected function _getName($name)
{
    return $name . ' - FOOBAR';
}
```

So in the view I did `Debug($user)`, and heres the result:

```
'properties' => [
        'id' => (int) 32,
        'name' => 'Daniel Pedro', //<- Clean Value
        'email' => 'daniel@gmail.com',
    ],
    'dirty' => [],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
```

As you can notice the property `name` is with the original value `Daniel Pedro`, so I thought I did something wrong at `_getName` but when I look at the input at form the value was `Daniel Pedro - FOOBAR`.

My question is, how can I show the mutated values at Debug?

Comment: You really want to have the `properties` key to be overwritten with the mutated values? And this _must_ happen when using `debug()`? How about an additional key that holds the mutated values, or maybe extract the values and debug them separately instead?

Comment: Good point, what do you think could be the best approach? Could you give me a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debug the values separately

The most simple way to check the properties with their possible muatated values, is by extracting the visible properties, something like

```
debug($entity->extract($entity->visibleProperties()));
```

This won't include the ones that have been defined as "hidden" in the `$_hidden` property, if you need them too, then you'll have to explicitly include them

```
debug($entity->extract(array_merge($entity->visibleProperties(), $entity->hidden())));
```

### Extend the debug info

If you'd wanted to somehow include this in the debug output of entities in general, then you'll have to overwrite the [**`EntityTrait::__debugInfo()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#___debugInfo) method and add the mutated properties in there.

Simple example, in your entity class (you can create a base entity class that all your entites extend so that you have this functionality in all entities):

```
public function __debugInfo()
{
    $info = parent::__debugInfo();

    $info['propertiesIncludingPossiblyMutatedValues'] =
        $this->extract(array_keys($this->_properties));

    return $info;
}
```

Or if you'd wanted to see only the ones that have really been mutated:

```
public function __debugInfo()
{
    $info = parent::__debugInfo();

    $info['mutated'] = array_diff(
        $this->extract(array_keys($this->_properties)),
        $this->_properties
    );

    return $info;
}
```

This should give you a hint of how things work.